# Checagem de valor dentro de object não está funcionando

Tags: json

Olá,

tenho uma API que me retorna a response:

```js
{
    "resultSetMetadata": {
        "count": 63,
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 100
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "receivableBillId": 2048,
            "installmentId": 1,
            "conditionTypeId": "AT",
            "dueDate": "2019-12-27",
            "balanceDue": 0.0,
            "generatedBoleto": true
        },
        {
            "receivableBillId": 2048,
            "installmentId": 2,
            "conditionTypeId": "AT",
            "dueDate": "2020-01-27",
            "balanceDue": 1000,
            "generatedBoleto": true
        },
```

e assim vai.

quero um código me retorne o installmendId que atenda as condições dadas
balanceDue > 0 e generatedBoleto = true. Nesse exemplo o output do installmentId seria = 2

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if (response.balanceDue > 0){
    if (response.generatedBoleto = true){
    numeroParcela = response.installmentId
}}
console.log(numeroParcela)
```

Porém ao rodar esse código, dá o seguinte erro: ReferenceError: numeroParcela is not defined
o que está errado ?

Comment: `balanceDue` é uma _chave_ dentro de _objetos_ de uma array chamada `results` dentro do `response`. Logo, `response.balanceDue` vai dar sempre _undefined_ porque não existe, e com isso, a variável `numeroParcela`, que está dentro de uma condição que **não foi satisfeita**, não existe quando o  `console.log` é executado. Sem citar o erro do sinal simples `=` dentro `if`.

Comment: Como eu faço para fazer a checagem com os valores das chaves então ?

Comment: Vc tem que percorrer a array. Poderia ser com um for.

Comment: var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    var numeroParcela = 0;
    var chave = 0;
    for (chave in response) {
    if (response[chave].balanceDue > 1){
        if (response[chave].generatedBoleto == false){
    numeroParcela === response[chave].installmentId;
}}
++chave;
}
console.log(numeroParcela)

Testei esse código e está me retornando sempre o valor 0 O que pode ser ?

Answer (score -1):

No seu código você está fazendo a checagem do `response.generatedBoleto` com um `=` só e não com 2 ou 3 (sendo que 2 checa se é igual e 3 checa se até o tipo do dado é igual), ou seja, a condição está errada, o que está impedindo o código de entrar nesse `if` e assim atribuir o valor à `numeroParcela`. Lembrando também que a variável `numeroParcela` deve ser iniciada antes.

```
    var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if (response.balanceDue > 0){
    if (response.generatedBoleto == true){
    numeroParcela = response.installmentId
}}
console.log(numeroParcela)
```

Comment: O problema não é só esse. Veja o meu comentário acima.